# Run time error "483" "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, runtime-error

I am trying to have a Custom Sort for a Table for the Specific Worksheet but I get the Run time error "483" "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I am Taking Worksheet Name and Custom List Order as String inputs from user.

```
Option Explicit    
Sub SortRiskArea()

Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim Tb, Rb

Dim shtName As String
    shtName = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the Worksheet Name that you want to sort." & vbNewLine & " Ex: Risk Register ", Title:="Hello", Default:="Risk Register")
    shtName = Trim(shtName)

Dim strName As String
    strName = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the Sort Order for Risk Area" & vbNewLine & " Ex: Commercial, Technological, Management, Reputational, Governance, Operational", Title:="Hello", Default:="Commercial, Technological, Management, Reputational, Governance, Operational")
    strName = Replace(strName, " ", "")

Set wk = Sheets(shtName)

If shtName = "Risk Register" Then Tb = "Table1"
If shtName = "SAP BI" Then Tb = "Table13"
If shtName = "SAP BO" Then Tb = "Table14"
If shtName = "SAP BW" Then Tb = "Table15"
If shtName = "SAP PM" Then Tb = "Table16"
If shtName = "Mobility" Then Tb = "Table17"
If shtName = "SAP FI" Then Tb = "Table18"
If shtName = "SAP Service Desk" Then Tb = "Table19"

Rb = "[Risk Area]"
Rb = Tb & Rb

     Error Lines   > ActiveWorkbook.wk.ListObjects(Tb).Sort. _
                     SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Rb), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
                     strName, _
                     DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.wk.ListObjects(Tb).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B5").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: @Davesexcel I have edited the question please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You've been rather unlucky in your code as most elements are nearly right, but, unfortunately the key ones are missing the last little bit of accuracy. Here's the list:

1. The line `ActiveWorkbook.wk.ListObjects(Tb).Sort` is trying to access a property of `ActiveWorkbook` that doesn't exist. `wk` is a `Sheet` object in itself that, by its absence in this line `Set wk = Sheets(shtName)` assumes the `ActiveWorkbook`. So the line should just be `wk.ListObjects(Tb).Sort` on both occasions. Better, you'd also set `wk` explicitly like so: `Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)` or `Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)`
2. Because you haven't explicitly set it, this line `Key:=Range(Rb)` assumes the `ActiveSheet` as opposed to your target sheet. So it should say `Key:=wk.Range(Rb)`
3. Custom sort orders are tricky beasts. I'm afraid your code won't work even though you will feel you have virtually exactly copied the auto-generated macro code. The way it actually works is that you create a `CustomList` in the `Application` object and then reference its index with an `Integer`. In the sample code below you'll see how to do that but you should be aware it will only work if your custom items are `Strings`.
4. Your last line will probably not do what you want because `Range("xx").Select` will again occur on the `ActiveSheet` whereas you want the target sheet to be selected.

A few other more general coding points:

1. You should declare each variable explicitly. So this line `Dim Tb, Rb` isn't so great as each will be `Variants` which is just adding unnecessary processing time and is making debugging harder.
2. The user input boxes are asking an awful lot of the user. He/she has to be sure there isn't a single typo or wrong sheet/custom value entry, otherwise an unhandled error will occur. This task is ideally suited to a `Userform` where you could have one `ComboBox` with all your target sheet names and one `ListBox` with your custom order items. If you changed the `ComboBox ColumnCount` to 2 then you could create a sheet name - table name map too. Maybe have a quick read of `Userforms` to see how to do this; it's really very easy.
3. The code would be easier to manage if you created a map of `Sheet` to `ListObject`. You'd only need to do that once and you could run your programme as many times as you liked without all of those `If` statements each time. You'd also be able to keep more control of any changes and of your object setting.

The code below shows you how to do all this. It's not perfect coding but it makes each point without undue distraction:

```
Sub SortRiskArea()
    Dim tableMapping As Collection
    Dim map(1) As Variant
    Dim sortItems As Variant
    Dim sortSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sortObject As ListObject
    Dim sortKey As Range
    Dim sortOrder As Integer
    Dim userInput As String

    'Create the map of sheets to tables
    'Note: you'd do this at module-level if there are repeated sorts.
    Set tableMapping = New Collection
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Risk Register")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table1")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP BI")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table13")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP BO")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table14")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP BW")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table15")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP PM")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table16")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobility")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table17")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP FI")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table18")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name
    Set map(0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP Service Desk")
    Set map(1) = map(0).ListObjects("Table19")
    tableMapping.Add map, map(0).Name

    'Acquire the target sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        userInput = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the Worksheet Name that you want to sort." & vbNewLine & " Ex: Risk Register ", Title:="Hello", Default:="Risk Register")
        sortItems = Empty
        sortItems = tableMapping(userInput)
        If IsEmpty(sortItems) Then MsgBox "Invalid entry."
    Loop Until Not IsEmpty(sortItems)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set sortSheet = sortItems(0)
    Set sortObject = sortItems(1)
    Set sortKey = sortSheet.Range(sortObject.Name & "[Risk Area]")

    'Acquire the custom sort order
    userInput = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the Sort Order for Risk Area" & vbNewLine & " Ex: Commercial, Technological, Management, Reputational, Governance, Operational", Title:="Hello", Default:="Commercial, Technological, Management, Reputational, Governance, Operational")
    userInput = Replace(userInput, " ", "")
    Application.AddCustomList Split(userInput, ",")
    sortOrder = Application.CustomListCount

    'Conduct the sort
    With sortObject.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=sortKey, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=sortOrder, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    'Safe select "B5"
    sortSheet.Activate
    sortSheet.Range("B5").Select
End Sub
```